# UITableViewCell change selectedBackgroundView alpha?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to change **`alpha`** for the `selectedBackgroundView` of the `UITableViewCell`. So I do the following:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    UIView *bgView = [UIView new];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bgView.alpha = 0.5;//This setting has no effect
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
}
```

Cell selected in red color, but alpha settings has no effect for bgView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[bgView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

**EDIT::**
There is a known issue in providing alpha values on to the subviews. Look at this thread for better understanding:[iOS controlling UIView alpha behaviour for subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581994/ios-controlling-uiview-alpha-behaviour-for-subviews)

Answer (score 3):

```
// set selection color

UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
[myBackView release];
```

Hope this link is useful for you.

[Changing background color of selected cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418189/iphone-uitableviewcell-changing-background-color-of-selected-cell)

[UITableView Cell selected Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color)